# extract array values from a function

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Below is a function in PHP I created which returns some product information in an array. On the web page where I am calling this function I want to be able to specify exact array elements for example just the product description ($result2['itm_desc']). Please can someone point me in the right direction as to do this. I would assume you call a function like fetch array but i'm not quite sure how to execute this.

```
public function getAllReelImages(){
$sql = "SELECT id FROM $this->table3 WHERE itm_cat = 2 ORDER BY id ASC";
echo "<br /><br />";
$stmt = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);

/*fetch values*/

while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){
echo "<br /><br />";

$sql2 = "SELECT itm_details.id,itm_details.itm_make,itm_details.itm_model,itm_details.itm_desc,itm_pic_detail.itm_pic_name, itm_value.itm_sale_price 
FROM 
itm_details, itm_pic_detail, itm_value 
WHERE 
itm_details.id = {$result['id']} AND itm_pic_detail.id = {$result['id']} 
AND itm_value.id = {$result['id']} ORDER BY id ASC"; 

$stmt2 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql2);
while($result2 = $stmt2->fetch_array()){
echo ($result2['id']); echo"<br />";
echo ($result2['itm_make']); echo"<br />";
echo ($result2['itm_model']); echo"<br />";
echo ($result2['itm_desc']); echo"<br />";
echo ($result2['itm_sale_price']); echo"<br />";
echo "<img src='$this->dir"."{$result2['itm_pic_name']}'><br />";
echo"<br />";
echo $value; 
}
}
}
```

Comment: You really need to tag your questions with the language you are using. This is the third time you receive such comment.

Comment: Why is there no indentation in your code? Yuk!

Answer (score 0):

First of all.. **Your code is pretty bad.** I made it little bit more clear. For example: `echo ($result2['id']); echo"<br />";` TO-> `echo $result2['id'] . '<br />';` (for future references.)

They way your code is at the moment. You wont add anything to an array, since you echo them right away. I made my version, that would first create the array and then later you can use that array..in any way you want :)

And doesn't the `ORDER BY` use by default as ASC?

I also changed the first query more dynamic.

**NOTE:** I'm not very good with mysql table joining, somebody must validate the second query. But in my eyes, its absolutely incorrect. However, I'm posting this in the reference for creating an array with a function and then displaying it.

**NOTE2:** I hope your question was about PHP o.0

```
# This should be in some class ?!
function getAllReelImages ($category) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $this->table3 . "` WHERE `itm_cat` = '" . $category . "' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
    $stmt = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
        $sql2 = "SELECT `itm_details.id`, `itm_details.itm_make`, `itm_details.itm_model`, `itm_details.itm_desc`, `itm_pic_detail.itm_pic_name`, `itm_value.itm_sale_price` FROM `itm_details`, `itm_pic_detail`, `itm_value` WHERE `itm_details.id` = '" . $result['id'] . "' AND `itm_pic_detail.id` = '" . $result['id'] . "' AND `itm_value.id` = '" . $result['id'] . "' ORDER BY `id` ASC"; 
        $stmt2 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql2);
        while($result2 = $stmt2->fetch_array()){
            $returns[$result2['id']]['id'] = $result2['id'];
            $returns[$result2['id']]['itm_make'] = $result2['itm_make'];
            $returns[$result2['id']]['itm_model'] = $result2['itm_model'];
            $returns[$result2['id']]['itm_desc'] = $result2['itm_desc'];
            $returns[$result2['id']]['itm_sale_price'] = $result2['itm_sale_price'];
            $returns[$result2['id']]['itm_pic_name'] = $this->dir . $result2['itm_pic_name'];
        }
    }
    return $returns;
}

# Display the results:
echo '<br /><br />';
foreach (getAllReelImages(2) as $img_id => $img_value) {
    echo $img_id . '<br>';
    echo $img_value['itm_make'] . '<br>';
    echo $img_value['itm_model'] . '<br>';
    echo $img_value['itm_desc'] . '<br>';
    echo $img_value['itm_sale_price'] . '<br>';
    echo $img_value['itm_pic_name'] . '<br>';
    echo '<hr>';
}
echo '<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks very much. A really helpful reply that's sorted my problem.:)